# How to transform items using sklearn Pipeline?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a simple scikit-learn `Pipeline` of two steps: a `TfIdfVectorizer` followed by a `LinearSVC`.

I have fit the pipeline using my data. All good.

Now I want to transform (not predict!) an item, using my fitted `pipeline`.

I tried `pipeline.transform([item])`, but it gives a different result compared to `pipeline.named_steps['tfidf'].transform([item])`. Even the shape and type of the result is different: the first is a 1x3000 CSR matrix, the second a 1x15000 CSC matrix. Which one is correct? Why do they differ?

How do I transform items, i.e. get an item's vector representation before the final estimator, when using scikit-learn's `Pipeline`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't call a transform method on a pipeline which contains Non-transformer on last step.
If you wan't to call transfrom on such pipeline last estimator must be a transformer.

Even [`transform` method doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.transform) says so:

> Applies transforms to the data, and the transform method of the
> final estimator. Valid only if the final estimator implements
> **transform**.

Also, there is no method to use every estimator except last one.
Thou you can make your own Pipeline, and inherit everything from scikit-learn's Pipeline, but add one method, something like:

```
def just_transforms(self, X):
    """Applies all transforms to the data, without applying last 
       estimator.

    Parameters
    ----------
    X : iterable
        Data to predict on. Must fulfill input requirements of first step of
        the pipeline.
    """
    Xt = X
    for name, transform in self.steps[:-1]:
        Xt = transform.transform(Xt)
    return Xt
```

Answer (score 8):

The reason why the results are different (and why calling `transform` even workds) is that `LinearSVC` also has a transform (now deprecated) that does feature selection

If you want to transform using just the first step, `pipeline.named_steps['tfidf'].transform([item])` is the right thing to do.
If you would like to transform using all but the last step, olologin's answer provides the code.

By default, **all** steps of the pipeline are executed, so also the transform on the last step, which is the feature selection performed by the LinearSVC.